# Inventory tab blank in Catalog->Manage Products in Magento

Tags: php, magento, amazon-web-services, magento-1.9

I am facing these weird problem in our magento store and any suggestion regarding this can be helpful.

**Problem** : I need to update the stock for individual product from magento backend itself,but the inventory tab is showing blank.
Inventory tab is blank in Catalog->Manage Products->Click on any product to edit. You can see there is inventory in the left navigation panel. when i click on it, there is a blank page.

Here is the screenshot:
https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/29SWtrGY.png

I have tried restarting AWS instance, also disabled the magento cache management and then checked with the inventory tab, but still its showing blank.

I have also checked with the plugins, and saw that we are not using any inventory plugin to update the inventory , and i believe that other plugins too cannot intefere with such kind of thing in magento.

Comment: Fatal error looks to be occurring. You will need to view your server log or turn on error reporting so you can see what it's saying

Comment: You have no footer (at least in your screen cap) so that usually indicates fatal error, is why i say that.

Comment: @Rasclatt  there is footer available, not shown in the screenshot. i enabled the error reporting and my admin panel shows blank page.

Comment: Where can be the problem, still couldnt figure it out. we are using magmi for uploading the products. can that be the problem??

Comment: I have the same problem!
Magento 1.9.2.2 is "clean"...

Comment: Got the same problem here on Magento 1.9.2.4, after importing a product programmatically, so I highly guess your problem is also related to imported products. I am on the way comparing database rows from that broken product with rows from a working product, but at first sight I see no differences. Any hints?

Comment: first see whether you have integrated any plugins , or check your chrome console first to see any js errros in this ,may be your plugins are interrupting this page. In my case the CDN was the problem, and when i removed it, the errors went away

Comment: always use magmi to import the products, its highly recommended, i dnt know how exactly to use the same , but we used it for our store

Comment: @Anse, did your problem got solved??

Comment: @Coold: I have no JS errors or warnings in the browser console. Also, the inventory page is not interrupting, but the content area is just empty. I still have a footer. I did not use Magmi yet, as you said earlier that you did so and still had the blank inventory page problem. How did you solve the issue?

Comment: one of my js was not loaded properly, that was the issue and nothing else.

Comment: So you can recommend using Magmi for importing products now?

Comment: yes, will recommend, learn how to use that , need to understand how you have to make CSV in this, because you might have configurable products, which might have different colors, sizes, etc....it doesnt work for bundled products

Comment: and yes  , it works for simple products too

Comment: Found the reason why the inventory tab was blank - it was a buggy GiftVoucher extension. When I disable that extension, the inventory tab is displayed normally again. For others facing this issue: I can only recommend to watch out for buggy extensions, by removing their xml file in app/etc/modules/. If it's a newer issue you hadn't before, start with newly installed extensions first until the tab is working again.

Comment: Same problem here, same reason: GiftVoucher extension.